# Change 0's to 1's in a binary list so that there wouldn't be more than N consecutive zeros

Tags: python, list, binary-data

Consider the following list:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

The `1`s subdivide the list into 5 parts:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 1,   0, 0, 0]
```

I would like each part to have not more than `n` consecutive zeros (if possible) before a `1`, but you cannot erase the current `1`s. Also there should be no 1's following each other.

Quick example: let's say n = 3, `l`should be:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 1,   0, 0, 0]
```

For n = 2 it would be:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 1,   0, 0, 1]
```

For the first part, I did not include a `1` after two zeros because then you would have two `1`s following each other.

**Any idea how I can do this?**

Here is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
max_number_of_cells_per_list = 3
l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
print(l)
# Find position of 1
pos_1 =[i for i,x in enumerate(l) if x == 1]
# Get number of cells 
pos_1.insert(0,0)
numb_cells = np.diff(pos_1)

n = np.round(np.divide(numb_cells,max_number_of_cells_per_list))

k = 0
j = 0
for i,li in enumerate(l):
    if l[i] == 1:
        if n[k] > 1:
            add = int((i-j)/n[k])

            for jj in range(int(n[k])):

                if jj == n[k]-1:
                    jj = i
                else:
                    jj += add

                l[jj] = 1

        k += 1
        j = i



print(l)
```

If you try to run the code, you will see that it makes no difference to `l`. I don't understand why... but I am not too interested to find my mistake if you have better/different ideas.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using NumPy, here is a solution using it. Note that it is not vectorized, and I'm not really sure if you can vectorize it as we have to perform grouping operations on the array, and NumPy doesn't have much functionality for that (though it's possible that I just don't see it yet).

I will be using [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to get the `[0, ..., 1]` groups, and then check two cases: first, for arrays that don't actually end with `1` (a possible group at the end of the array), and for arrays that have more than `n + 2` zeros. And then I just insert `1` at each `n + 1` position making sure that there will be no two 1s together.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
n = 3  # or n = 2, or any other n >= 0 value

result = []
for array in np.split(a.copy(), np.where(a == 1)[0] + 1):
    last_index = -2 if array[-1] == 1 else None
    array[n:last_index:n + 1] = 1
    result.append(array)
np.concatenate(result)
# for n = 3: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
# for n = 2: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

---

Alternatively, instead of splitting the array in multiple parts and operating on them, we could operate only on indices of `1`. For example, here I get initial indices of `1`, and add more of them in between using `range`:

```
from itertools import tee

l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
n = 3 


def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3), ..."""
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def one_indices(seq, n):   
    """Returns new indices where we will put 1s"""
    indices = [index + 1 for index, value in enumerate(seq) if value == 1]
    complete_groups_count = len(indices)  # those that end with 1
    indices = [0, *indices, len(seq)]

    for group_index, (start, end) in enumerate(pairwise(indices), start=1):
        if group_index <= complete_groups_count:
            yield from range(start + n, end - 2, n + 1)
            yield end - 1
        else:  # last group that doesn't end with 1
            yield from range(start + n, end, n + 1)


result = [0] * len(l)
for index in one_indices(l, 3):
    result[index] = 1
result
# for n = 3: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
# for n = 2: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

This is probably more efficient than splitting and concatenating arrays as in the first example, but it's also more difficult to read.

---

Finally, as a bonus, here is a solution using pandas. I saw in your previous related questions that you were using it, so you may find it useful:

```
from functools import partial

import pandas as pd


def fill_ones(series, n):
    last_index = -2 if series.iloc[-1] == 1 else None
    series.iloc[n:last_index:n + 1] = 1
    return series


l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
s = pd.Series(l)
groups = s.shift().eq(1).cumsum()
fill_w_distance_3 = partial(fill_ones, n=3)
s.groupby(groups).transform(fill_w_distance_3).tolist()
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

fill_w_distance_2 = partial(fill_ones, n=2)
s.groupby(groups).transform(fill_w_distance_2).tolist()
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Wow ! This is a really great answer ! Thanks a lot !! :)